# OpenVZ fails on container create (Unable to get appcache tarball name)

Tags: virtual-machine, centos, virtualization, centos-7, openvz

I have OpenVZ installed on CentOS 7.1.

after i execute

```
vzctl create 101 --ostemplate debian-7.0-x86-minimal
```

i get

```
command /usr/sbin/vzpkg exited with error 8
Unable to get appcache tarball name for ve-basic.conf-sample with ostemplate debian-7.0-x86-minimal
Destroying Container private area: /vz/private/101
Warning: Container is in old data format, unregistration skipped
Container private area was destroyed
Creation of Container private area failed
```

I have template and basic conf:

```
[root@localhost vz]# ls /vz/template/cache/
debian-7.0-x86-minimal.tar.gz
[root@localhost vz]# 

[root@localhost vz]# ls /etc/vz/conf/
networks_classes      ve-cent.conf-sample     ve-vswap.1024MB.conf-sample  ve-vswap.256MB.conf-sample  ve-vswap.plesk.conf-sample
ve-basic.conf-sample  ve-confixx.conf-sample  ve-vswap.2048MB.conf-sample  ve-vswap.512MB.conf-sample  vps.vzpkgtools.conf-sample
[root@localhost vz]#
```

Server: HP ProLiant DL380 G5

Any help would be appreciate, because i've been googling for all day, with no luck :(

Comment: @eimantas-grabrielius Getting the same issue here. Did you ever find a fix?